# MySQL update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, unix-timestamp

I have a MySQL table which has the following columns

```
urlByCustomer table
----------------------------------------------
|customerID | TeamID | date | numUrlsConsumed|
----------------------------------------------
|           |        |      |                | 
----------------------------------------------

urlmapping

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments    MIME
urlMappingID    bigint(20)  No           
customerID  int(11) Yes     0        
activityID  int(11) Yes     0        
contactID   int(11) Yes     0        
fullURL mediumtext  Yes     NULL         
lastModified    timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP        
developerSandbox    varchar(25) Yes
```

I've got this code that is being executed to update the table

```
 $start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
                             $end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59'));
                             $countAllThisGuysVals = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT`customerID`,`fullURL`)  
                                                      FROM `urlmapping` 
                                                      WHERE `urlMappingID` >= $ORIGINAL_COPY 
                                                      AND `customerID` = $currentCustomerID";
                            $countTheVals= $conn->query($countAllThisGuysVals);
                            $countedfinal =0;
                            foreach ($countTheVals as $countRow) {
                                $countedfinal = array_sum($countRow)/2;
                            }
                                $tableUpdateQuery = "UPDATE `urlByCustomer`
                                                SET `date` = NOW()
                                                WHERE `customerID`= $currentCustomerID AND 
                                                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) BETWEEN '{$start}' and '{$end}'";

                                $conn->exec($tableUpdateQuery);

                                 $tableUpdateQuery = "UPDATE `urlByCustomer`
                                                SET `numUrlsConsumed` = $countedfinal
                                                WHERE `customerID`= $currentCustomerID AND 
                                                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) BETWEEN '{$start}' and '{$end}'";
                                $conn->exec($tableUpdateQuery);
                                echo "update path <br>";
                                $tableModified = true;
                                $originalLPID++;
```

Variables are pretty much all declared, but the declarations are spread out, so I'm just posting this part to shorten it. The update query to the date column seems to be working, but the second update isn't. It worked 17 minutes ago though, so I'm confused since the only thing that changed between the next test was that I added some new values that should be causing it to update that column.

Idk. I guess one possiblity could be the UNIX_TIMESTAMP. I'm running this in Parallels on a Mac, so I'm not sure what that translates to for timestamps.

Comment: So instead of working, it's doing what, exactly?

Comment: Could you give the structure for `urlmapping` please, and in your code, you refer to table `urlByCustomer` but in your post you call it `customerByUrl` - is this the same table?

Comment: Have you echoed your query and run directly in your database, like in phpmyadmin or something like that? To check the errors?

Comment: How is the $ORIGiNAL_COPY resolved at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're changing the value of "date" in your first update, without considering the fact that your second update will now not find the same rows in the WHERE clause (as you've just changed the date).

You can do the updates in a single statement: :

```
UPDATE urlByCustomer
SET `date` = NOW()
, numUrlsConsumed = $countedfinal
WHERE customerID= $currentCustomerID 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) BETWEEN '{$start}' and '{$end}'
```